# g++ doesn't show expected linker errors

Tags: linux, linker, g++, shared-libraries

I'm new to linux development, but have many years experience in Windows development. I'm trying to link a program using:

g++ -fPIC -shared $(OBJ_FILES) -o libMyLib.so

The odd thing is, this works. This is odd because there should be additional shared libraries I need to link in for this to be successful. So I was just trying to do this one step at a time and expected linker errors at this point, but saw none. What am I missing?

Comment: Thanks...this answers my question, but unfortunately I don't see a way to confirm this as a duplicate.

Comment: Well I'm glad it helped!

Answer (score 2):

Unfulfilled dependencies that are to be met by shared libraries are linked in during runtime, not during compilation.